# Flip order of elements function in MATLAB R2011a

Tags: matlab, matrix, flip

I am using MATLAB version R2011a, a friend of mine is using R2014b which contains the function "Flip", which flips the order of elements, this function is vital to our program that compares Matrix'es.

My problem is R2011a does not have this function, it has fliplr,flipud and flipdim. I have tried using fliplr and then flipud to try and recreate the same function but eventually it doesn't work since i'm using the function corr which requires using that it's two arguments be the same dimensions.

I need advise on how to create the flip function that is available on R2014b.

The function that is problematic:

```
%This function gets the DNA signiture with the relative freq of each perm at
%the refernce text, the DNA signiture with the relative freq of each perm at
%the compare text, and the MaxPerm, and return the relative editor distance  
%between the 2 texts. 

function [distance]=EditorDistance2 (RefDNAWithFreq,CmpDNAWithFreq,MaxPerm)

if MaxPerm>2
   MaxPerm=2; 
end

str='Editor Distance compare begun';
disp(str);

distance=[];

for PermLength=1:MaxPerm

    freq=sum(0:PermLength);
    PermInitial=freq+1;
    permEnd=freq+PermLength;

    %create an ordered matrix of all the perms with length "PermLength"
    %in the ref text
    CurRefPerms=RefDNAWithFreq(:,freq:permEnd); 
    OrderedRefCurPerms=sortrows(CurRefPerms);
    OrderedRefCurPerms=flip(OrderedRefCurPerms);
    OrderedRefCurPerms(:,1)=[];
    OrderedRefCurPerms=ZeroCutter(OrderedRefCurPerms);


    %create an ordered matrix of all the perms with length "PermLength"
    %in the cmp text
    CurcmpPerms=CmpDNAWithFreq(:,freq:permEnd); 
    OrderedCmpCurPerms=sortrows(CurcmpPerms);
    OrderedCmpCurPerms=flip(OrderedCmpCurPerms);
    OrderedCmpCurPerms(:,1)=[];
    OrderedCmpCurPerms=ZeroCutter(OrderedCmpCurPerms);

    len1=size(OrderedRefCurPerms,1);
    len2=size(OrderedCmpCurPerms,1);

    edit=1; 

    matrix=zeros(len2,len1);

    %initiate first row of the first stirng
    for i=2:len1
        matrix(1,i)=matrix(1,i-1)+1;
    end 

    %initiate first column of the second stirng
    for i=2:len2
        matrix(i,1)=matrix(i-1,1)+1;
    end

    %start algoritem
    for i=2:len2
        for j=2:len1


            if OrderedRefCurPerms(j-1,:)==OrderedCmpCurPerms(i-1,:)
                edit=0;
            end


            if (i>2 & j>2 &  OrderedRefCurPerms(j-1,:)==OrderedCmpCurPerms(i-2,:) &  RefDNAWithFreq(j-2)==CmpDNAWithFreq(i-1) )

                matrix(i,j)= min([matrix(i-1,j)+1,...       deletion
                                  matrix(i,j-1)+1,...       insertion
                                  matrix(i-2,j-2)+1,...     substitution
                                  matrix(i-1,j-1)+edit...   transposition
                                  ]);       

            else
                matrix(i,j) = min([matrix(i-1,j)+1,...      deletion
                                   matrix(i,j-1)+1,...      insertion
                                   matrix(i-1,j-1)+edit...  substitution
                                   ]);
            end


            edit=1;
        end

    end

    %The Distance is the last elment of the matrix.
    if i~=1
        tempdistance = matrix( floor( len2 / 3 ) , floor( len1 / 3 ) );
        tempdistance=tempdistance/floor(len2/3);
    else
        tempdistance = matrix( len2,len1 );
        tempdistance= tempdistance/len2;        
    end

    tempdistance=1-tempdistance;

    distance=[distance tempdistance];
end

end
```

I will further explain myself, the function which I am trying to use is A=flip(A)

The function that causes me problems is this one

%This function gets the DNA signiture with the relative freq of each perm at
    %the refernce text, the DNA signiture with the relative freq of each perm at
    %the compare text, and the MaxPerm, and return the corralation between the 2 texts.

```
function    [Corvector]=CorrelationCompare(RefDNAWithFreq,CmpDNAWithFreq,MaxPerm)

str='corraltion compare begun';
disp(str);
%this vector will contain the corralation between the freqs of 
%each perms vector(each length)
Corvector=[]; 


for PermLength=1:MaxPerm

    freq=sum(0:PermLength);
    PermInitial=freq+1;
    permEnd=freq+PermLength;


    %Cor is correlation between the 2 texts
    refPerms=RefDNAWithFreq(:,freq);
    cmpPerms=CmpDNAWithFreq(:,freq);

    refPerms=ZeroCutter(refPerms);
    cmpPerms=ZeroCutter(cmpPerms);
    tempCor=corr(refPerms,cmpPerms);
    Corvector =[Corvector tempCor];


%     making a graph of the perms, and the relative freq of the texts.
    x=ZeroCutter ( RefDNAWithFreq(:,PermInitial:permEnd) );
    y1=refPerms;
    y2=cmpPerms;

    xchars=char(x);

    Xcols=size(x,1);
    o=ones(Xcols,1);
    xco=mat2cell(xchars,o,PermLength);
    xaxis=(1:Xcols);

    figure
    stem(xaxis,y1,'r');
    hold
    stem(xaxis,y2,'g');
    set(gca,'XTick',xaxis)
    set(gca,'XTickLabel',xco,'fontname','david');
    xlabel('Perms');
    ylabel('Perm frequency');
    TitleOfGraph=sprintf('comapre between reference text to the compared, %d letters perm\n correlation=%f',PermLength,Corvector(PermLength));
    legend('reference','compared');
    title(TitleOfGraph);

end


end
```

The Error that I recieve when using a diffrent flip command is

```
??? Error using ==> corr at 102
X and Y must have the same number of rows.

Error in ==> CorrelationCompare at 27
tempCor=corr(refPerms,cmpPerms);
```

I apologize for the long codes but it's hard to explain it all since it's a     big project and a lot of it was done by my partner

Comment: What do you want to flip (vectors, matrices...), and along which dimension? Even better, post some small example code that reproduces the problem

Comment: I am trying to Flip matrix'es that contain numbers of repeats of permutations in two texts, the thing with using flip is that if you use it like this: B=flip(A), it copies the dimensions. which makes sure for me to have the same dimensions in corr.

Comment: I think you still need to explain what is "problematic" with the edited codes that you just posted. If you were looking to have `flip` from `2014B` version, which you don't have in your `2011A` version, then check out the posted solution? If there's something more, you have to be more precise about it and explain them.

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code with explanation

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you -

```
function out = flip_hacked(A,dim)

%// Get an array of all possible dimensions
dims = 1:ndims(A);

%// Interchange first dimension and dim
dims(dim) = 1;
dims(1) = dim;
A1 = permute(A,[dims]);

%// Reshape A1 into a 2D matrix and then flip along the first dimension,
%// which would correspond to the flipping along dim and then interchange dim 
%// and first dim again to keep the size of data same as input and elements 
%// being flipped along dim for the desired output
A2 = reshape(A1,size(A1,1),[]);
out = permute(reshape(A2(end:-1:1,:),size(A1)),dims);

return;
```

It follows the same syntax as the official **[`flip`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html)** function that's stated in the official documentation as follows -

> B = flip(A,dim) reverses the order of the elements in A along
>   dimension dim. For example, if A is a matrix, then flip(A,1) reverses
>   the elements in each column, and flip(A,2) reverses the elements in
>   each row.

Comment: There's `flipdim` which does this. Perhaps the OP wants the "along the first non-singleton dimension" behaviour of the one-input version of `flip`? It's not really clear what he wants

Comment: @LuisMendo Huh! Wow, I didn't see `flipdim`! Yeah it seems to be the same! Yeah OP has to be clear on this.

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code with explanation, please check it out

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the generic solution provided by *Divakar* you could simply use:

```
flip = @(A) A(end:-1:1, :);
A = flip(A);
```

To reverse the elements in each column of a matrix `A`. Even simpler:

```
A = A(end:-1:1, :);
```